# How to concatenate several create table sentences so the script runs everything with one execute command?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, say I have this SQL Script:

```
create table Person
(
    id int primary key,
    name nvarchar(40)
)

create table Country
(
    id int primary key,
    name nvarchar(40)
)
```

How can I have those commands in a single file and be able to run it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `GO` after each create table statement.